# why new RegExp(".. ")({}) equals "ct "

Tags: actionscript

My code:
`trace(new RegExp(".. ")({}))`

and console print "ct "

it's so strange, is there anybody know why call an RegExp instance with a {} will return string "ct "?

Answer (score 0):

{} seems to be an objeCT:

```
trace(new RegExp('...............')({})); // [object Object]
```